# infinite series integration $x^2 \tan^{-1} x^3$, why can't you directly integrate the infinite series representation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals

We have $$(\arctan(x^3))' = \frac{3x^2}{1+x^6} = \frac{3x^2}{1-(-x^6)} = 3x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x^6)^n.$$

Integrating this gives $$3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{6n+5}}{6n+3}.$$

Apparently it's correct except for the $\frac{1}{6n+3}$ which should be $(2n+1)$, if i remember correctly. But why? With many series you can directly use the integration rules you know, so why not here?

Why should I here write out the original infinite series and then integrate part by part and then make an infinite equation out of that?

Comment: Apart from everything else, why not by parts?

Comment: Take care : $\tan^{-1}(x)\neq \frac 1 {\tan(x)}$ but $\tan^{-1}(x)=\text{arctan}(x)$

Comment: Oh, since I hadn't read the originally non-Texified OP I didn't see you were confusing $\arctan(x)$ and $1/\tan(x)$.

Comment: I did mean tan^-1 with arctan. Someone changed it wrongly

Comment: I am on my mobile so it difficult to correct. Can someone correct the wrong eddit. I did not mean 1/tan x but arctan aka tan^-1

Comment: Concerning the integration you should have integrated $x^2 x^{6n}=x^{6n+2}$ and not $x^{6n}$ alone to get $6n+3$ at the denominator (and thus the $(2n+1)$ factor you wished).

Comment: To echo Raymond Manzoni's comment, $\dfrac{3}{6n + 3} = \dfrac{1}{2n + 1}$. (The power of $x$ in your series is not currently OK, however.)

Answer (score 1):

Well,

$$\begin{align}
\int 3x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^6)^n \,\textrm{d}x
& = \int 3x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{12n} \,\textrm{d}x + \int -3x^8 \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{12n} \,\textrm{d}x \\ 
& = 3 \int \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{12n + 2} \,\textrm{d}x - 3\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{12n + 8} \,\textrm{d}x \\ 
& = 3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^{12n+2} \,\textrm{d}x - 3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^{12n+8} \,\textrm{d}x \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3x^{12n+3}}{12n+3} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3x^{12n+9}}{12n+9} = \textrm{arctan}(x^3)\end{align}.
$$

Or even shorter:
$$\begin{align}
\int 3x^2\sum_{n \ge 0} (-x^6)^n \,\textrm{d}x & = 3\sum_{n \ge 0} \int (-x^6)^n\cdot x^2 \,\textrm{d}x = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{3 x^3 (-x^6)^n}{6n+3} \\ & = \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n (x^3)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \arctan (x^3).
\end{align}$$

Comment: what are you doing in the first step? Plus it is (x^2)*arctan (x^3) and not arctanh(x^3). You seem to deviate even more from the answer. My answer is almost correct. Only the 1/(6n+1) part in my answer is not correct and should be 1/(2n+1)

Comment: @strateeg32 Fixed.